# How to select multiple columns values same rows from single table

Tags: select, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a SQL Server table. Now this table has columns like primary key `Id`, `A, B, C, D, E, F, G`

Now I want to select rows from this table like this

```
A=A, B=B, C=C, D=D and G > 132
```

So I am trying to select rows from this table which rows `A,B,C,D` columns has same data and G column data > 132.

So how can I do that ? Thank you.

I tried this query but returning same Id rows

```
    SELECT TableA.Id,TableA.UserId,TableA.MaximumHp,TableA.Attack,TableA.Defense,TableA.SpAttack,TableA.SpDefense,TableA.Speed
FROM myTable as TableA
Inner Join myTable as TableB on 
TableA.MaximumHp = TableB.MaximumHp
  AND TableA.Attack = TableB.Attack
  AND TableA.Defense = TableB.Defense
    AND TableA.SpAttack = TableB.SpAttack
      AND TableA.SpDefense = TableB.SpDefense
        AND TableA.Speed = TableB.Speed
       AND TableA.Id != TableB.Id
```

SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: I don't understand--A=A, B=B, C=C, and D=D will *always* be true. What are you trying to get to? Sample data would be helpful.

Comment: Do you mean that the column A has a value 'A'?

Comment: I am trying to select rows from this table which rows A,B,C,D columns has same data.

Comment: So, what data type are the columns A, B, C, D?

Comment: They can be both integer and varchar. Does that matter ?

Comment: Same data as **what**?? What do you compare it to???

Comment: These is comparison of rows. So i am comparing different rows columns data

Comment: He wants the duplicate rows. Since a,b,c,and d are not in the primary key, there can be multiple rows with A=1, B=1, C=1, D=1 for example. See my answer, below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I THINK what you mean is duplicates. Tell me if this is what you are looking for.

```
SELECT [Table].A, [Table].B, [Table].C, [Table].D, [Table].E, [Table].F, [Table].G
FROM [Table] LEFT JOIN (SELECT A, B, C, D FROM [Table] 
GROUP BY A, B, C, D
HAVING count(*) > 1)
AS sub ON ([Table].A=sub.A) AND ([Table].B=sub.B) AND ([Table].C=sub.C) AND ([Table].D=sub.D)
WHERE G>132 and sub.A is not null;
```

This will give you all the rows where a,b,c, and D are equal to another row in the table...and G > 132

Comment: Yes looking duplicates. Now going to check your answer thanks.

Comment: Hello. I tried but it returns all of the rows not duplicate ones : http://pastebin.com/qzMbkAZ2

Comment: If all of the rows in your table have a duplicate, then it will return all of them.

Comment: All the rows do not have duplicate. I made a minor mistake at where clause and now fixed it. Now trying again and Query is still running.

Comment: I hope this query isn't going into a game. Or if it is, I hope it's not going to be run while the game is in progress. I would only execute this when the game first loads or closes, otherwise it will take too long.

Comment: It is a game query but i am trying at my local host :) Somehow an important glitch happened and i have to find whether anybody abused or not ^^

Comment: wow it gave error when running : Msg 9002, Level 17, State 4, Line 1
The transaction log for database 'tempdb' is full. To find out why space in the log cannot be reused, see the log_reuse_wait_desc column in sys.databases - lol my ssd raid is full :D

Comment: Is the drive full, or just the log? You can increase the size of the log.

Comment: Drive was full. I reset the SQL service and 22 gb free space opened :D Now going to rerun the query and i will let you know the result.

Comment: It keeps failing because of the log file size. Even 33 gb is not enough. I need to change primary file group log file location. I added another log file but it did not use it and failed again. How can i do that ?

Comment: Update on the issue. Query is now running for 1 day and 1 hour. Used already more than 100 GB space. I hope it finishes this time. Still have 390 gb on that harddisk :D

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you want to join the table to itself

```
SELECT *
FROM Table t1
Inner Join Table t2 on t1.A = t2.A
  AND t1.B = t2.B
  AND t1.C = t2.C
  AND t1.D = t2.D
  AND t1.G > 132
  AND t1.ID <> t2.ID
```

Comment: Hello. I tried this but selecting same ID rows. t1 and t2 is same table here since i want to compare different rows of same table

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG ... look again  I am not comparing the same rows hence the last AND Clause `t1.ID <> t2.ID`

Comment: I don't get any error. Returning all of the rows at the table.

Comment: lol....have you evaluated what you should be getting?  make a simple test case and then verify that it works.

Comment: Yes i evaluated. I have many rows which are unique so the query should not return all of the rows at the table.