# Finding rows with same values in multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to find rows that have duplicate values, but only based off of a select number of columns, not a single column or the entire row. For example, if my table looked like this:

```
ID     Address    State    Name
-------------------------------
0      7 Brown    NY       John
1      3 Red      WX       Jane
2      7 Brown    WX       Ted
3      7 Brown    NY       Fred
```

My question would be:

> Find all ID's for rows where the row's Address and State field matched another row's Address and State field.

The answer to this query would be:

```
ID    Address    State    Name
------------------------------
0     7 Brown    NY       John
3     7 Brown    NY       Fred
```

Any Ideas?

Suggestions:
[How to select multiple columns values same rows from single table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8661794/how-to-select-multiple-columns-values-same-rows-from-single-table)

Comment: Perhaps tag with "TSQL" ?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Try the following:

```
SELECT A.*
FROM YourTable A
INNER JOIN (SELECT Address, State
            FROM YourTable
            GROUP BY Address, State
            HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) B
ON A.Address = B.Address AND A.State = B.State
```

Comment: ok, while these both work just fine. I think i will stick with this one. Thanks.

Comment: Better and simple way to handle this kind of scenario
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13807314/find-rows-where-the-same-two-column-values-recur

Comment: @himanshupareek66 I fail to see the difference. The reason for the join here we because op wanted the whole row where there were duplicates, not just address and state

Answer (score 4):

```
select *
from #table1
where Addr + St in (select Addr + St as FullAddr
             from #table1
             group by Addr + St
             having count(Addr+St) > 1)
```

Comment: The string concatenation operator in SQL is `||` not `+`. But it would be better to use `where (addr, st) in (select addr, st from ...)` anyway instead of concatenating strings (which might have problems with some combinations of address and state)