# Find Rows where the Same Two Column Values Recur

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given a table in SQL-Server like:

```
Id INTEGER
A  VARCHAR(50)
B  VARCHAR(50)
-- Some other columns
```

with no index on A or B, I wish to find rows where a unique combination of A and B occurs more than once.

I'm using the query

```
SELECT A+B, Count(A+B) FROM MyTable
GROUP BY A+B
HAVING COUNT(A+B) > 1
```

**First Question**

Is there a more time-efficient way to do this?  (I cannot add indices to the database)

**Second Question**

When I attempt to gain some formatting of the output by including a `,` in the concatenation:

```
SELECT A+','+B, Count(A+','+B) FROM MyTable
GROUP BY A+','+B
HAVING COUNT(A+','+B) > 1
```

The query fails with the error

```
Column 'MyDB.dbo.MyTable.A' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause
```

with a similar error for Column B.

How can I format the output to separate the two columns?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It would seem more natural to me to write:

```
SELECT A, B, Count(*) FROM MyTable
GROUP BY A, B
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

And it's the most efficient way of doing it (and so is the query in the question).

Similarly to the above query, you can rewrite your second query:

```
SELECT A + ',' + B, Count(*) FROM MyTable
GROUP BY A, B
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: so simple and accurate.