# Find number of rows identical one some, but different on another column

Tags: sql, postgresql

Say I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE data (
  PROJECT_ID VARCHAR,
  TASK_ID VARCHAR,
  REF_ID VARCHAR,
  REF_VALUE VARCHAR
);
```

I want to identify rows where

- `PROJECT_ID`, `REF_ID`, `REF_VALUE` are the same
- but `TASK_ID` are different.

The desired output is a list of `TASK_ID_1`, `TASK_ID_2` and `COUNT(*)` of such conflicts. So, for example,

```
DATA
+------------+---------+--------+-----------+
| PROJECT_ID | TASK_ID | REF_ID | REF_VALUE |
+------------+---------+--------+-----------+
|      1     |    1    |    1   |     1     |
|      1     |    1    |    1   |     2     |
|      1     |    2    |    1   |     1     |
|      1     |    2    |    1   |     2     |
+------------+---------+--------+-----------+


OUTPUT
+-----------+-----------+----------+
| TASK_ID_1 | TASK_ID_2 | COUNT(*) |
+-----------+-----------+----------+
|     1     |     2     |     2    |
|     2     |     1     |     2    |
+-----------+-----------+----------+
```

would mean that there are two entries with `TASK_ID == 1` and two entries with `TASK_ID == 2` that share the same values for the other three columns. The inherent symmetry in the output is fine.

How would I go about finding this information? I've tried joining the table onto itself and grouping, but this turned up more results for a single task than the table had rows altogether, so it's clearly wrong.

The database used is PostgreSQL, though a solution that applies to most common SQL systems would be preferable.

Comment: Find rows with same values. check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11056235/finding-rows-with-same-values-in-multiple-columns

Comment: Can you have three different taskid for same `PROJECT_ID, REF_ID, REF_VALUE` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a self join and aggregation:

```
select d1.task_id as task_id_1, d2.task_id as task_id_2, count(*)
from data d1 join
     data d2
     on d1.project_id = d2.project_id and
        d1.ref_id = d2.ref_id and
        d1.ref_value = d2.ref_value and
        d1.task_id <> d2.task_id
group by d1.task_id, d2.task_id;
```

Notes:

- Add the condition `d1.task_id < d2.task_id` if you want each pair to occur only once in the result set.
- This does not handle `NULL` values, although that is easy enough to handle.  Use `is not distinct from` instead of `=`.

You can also simplify this a bit with the `using` clause:

```
select d1.task_id as task_id_1, d2.task_id as task_id_2, count(*)
from data d1 join
     data d2
     using (project_id, ref_id, ref_value)
where d1.task_id <> d2.task_id
group by d1.task_id, d2.task_id;
```

You can get an idea of how many rows might be returned by using:

```
select d.project_id, d.ref_id, d.ref_value, count(distinct d.task_id), count(*)
from data d
group by d.project_id, d.ref_id, d.ref_value;
```

Comment: This is pretty much exactly what I did, but got wrong results from it. I'll check again to make sure I'm not just going crazy.

Comment: I must be going crazy. On small datasets it works fine, but on the bigger one I get a single result row with a COUNT(*) of over 4.5 million even though the input table has only around 100,000.

Comment: @IngoBürk . . . Presumably you have a lot of pairs that meet your conditions.

Comment: In that data there's only two distinct task IDs. And in fact they're evenly split duplicates, so the output should be 50k, not 4.5 million. I'm going to accept this answer for now but something is definitely wrong, just maybe not with the SQL.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I understand your question. This assume there are only two task for the same combination.

**[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/95b9bc/5)**

```
SELECT "PROJECT_ID", "REF_ID", "REF_VALUE",
       MIN("TASK_ID") as TASK_ID_1,
       MAX("TASK_ID") as TASK_ID_2,
       COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM Table1       
GROUP BY "PROJECT_ID", "REF_ID", "REF_VALUE"
HAVING MIN("TASK_ID") != MAX("TASK_ID") 
    -- COUNT(*) > 1 also should work
```

**OUTPUT**

I add more column to make clear what are the same elements:

```
| PROJECT_ID | REF_ID | REF_VALUE | task_id_1 | task_id_2 | cnt |
|------------|--------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----|
|          1 |      1 |         2 |         1 |         2 |   2 |
|          1 |      1 |         1 |         1 |         2 |   2 |
```