# Retrun True for rows with same values in multiple columns in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
id | code |
12 | US   | 
12 | US   |
13 | US   |
13 | AZ   |
14 | US   |
14 | AZ   |
```

I want to return a column that says True if the code for every pair is same and false if not. Want to check for pairs of ids. All id values in the column are in pairs

Expected Result of this question

```
id | match |
12 | TRUE
13 | FALSE
14 | FALSE
```

Tried solving it similar to : [Finding rows with same values in multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11056235/finding-rows-with-same-values-in-multiple-columns) but the answer was too long

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a `GROUP BY`. If the max(code) = min(code), they are equal.

```
select id, max(code) = min(code)
from tablename
group by id
```

You can also use count() instead, for example if the rows don't come in pairs.

```
select id, count(distinct code) = 1
from tablename
group by id
```